# Concrete5. Create new thumbnail type

Tags: types, thumbnails, concrete5

I am trying to create new thumbnail type, like this:

```
use Concrete\Core\File\Image\Thumbnail\Type\Type;

$type = new Type();
$type->setName( 'thumbnails name' );
$type->setHandle( 'block_handle' );
$type->setWidth( 250 );
$type->save();
```

On Concrete5 v7.5 everything working fine, but on v8.0.0 there is an error:

```
Call to undefined method Concrete\Core\File\Image\Thumbnail\Type\Type::setName()
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This change is documented here.](https://documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/package-developers-upgrading-your-packages-version-8)

Unfortunately  lot of the other documentation hasn't been updated yet.

Just replace

```
Concrete\Core\File\Image\Thumbnail\Type\Type
```

with

```
Concrete\Core\Entity\File\Image\Thumbnail\Type\Type
```